# SCNPhysicsBehavior - BallSocketJoint - change parameters

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, game-physics

I am still writing on my Ship-in-a-Cave game and still facing problems, especially with SceneKit.
One function I want the ship to be capable of is moving around rocks.
In a way of force-ray-connection, the rocks shall be attached to the ship and swing around, while the ship is moving.
I discovered the PhysicsBehaviors that ScnKit offers, and ‚BallSocketJoint’ does exactly what I want.
I found out that I need to set the Behavior (bodyA, anchorA, bodyB and anchorB with ‚Joint‘ as the container) in the same scene that all nodes are in, and later activate it from the GameViewController.
All this is working fine so far, except it doesn‘t seem possible to modify those parameters, when for example I want to change the distance of the two bodies.
I figured something like

> (self.sceneView.scene as! MainScene).Joint.anchorB = vector with new
> distance

should do it, but I am told that the SCNPhysicsBehavior has no member ‚anchorB‘.

Does anyone know how I can address the anchor-vectors (or even change the body-references)?
Is it possible at all?

in the main scene, the behavior is set:

> self.Joint = SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint(
> anchorA: SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)
> bodyB: rockNode.physicsBody!,
> anchorB: SCNVector3(x:0, y:-6, z:0),
> bodyA: shipNode.physicsBody!),

Later, the behavior is added to the scene:

> self.sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.addBehavior((self.sceneView.scene
> as! MainScene).Joint)

All this works fine, but it‘s not possible to change the parameters of ‚Joint‘, like I wrote earlier

> (self.sceneView.scene as! MainScene).Joint.anchorB = whatever.

Because the PhysicsBehavior has no member ‚anchorB‘.

The thing is: I understand that it‘s probably complicated to change the parameters while the simulation is running (that is, AFTER I added the Behavior to the scene).
All I would like to know is how to access the variables before the Behavior is running. This is probably just the usual way to deal with these variables (Class?), which I simply haven‘t learned yet?!
Maybe one more thing: Of course, I could simply define the entire behavior at the point where I need it - but then, I can‘t remove the behavior, because it‘s name is not understood outside of that particular routine.

Comment: I dont know if I understand you correctly, but you could probably put all your joint's into an array and then doing the modifications using the arraymembers. Have you some more code to explain your situation?

Comment: I added a few lines to the query above. Does this explain better now what I am after?

Comment: can you share a simplifyed version of your project?

Comment: I found the solution: set the entire behavior at the start, and setting it again at the point where I need it.